# Elementos se separan aun cuando hay margen 0 en HTML

Tags: html, css

EL problema es que estoy colocando un menú superior y toma una separación aun cuando lo tengo con margen=0 en los otros archivos tengo el mismo formato de menú y esos están bien, abarcan la anchura de la pantalla y no hay separación de los margenes arriba o abajo.

Ya intente reiniciando el servidor, cerrando el navegador y usar otro editor.

Este es el HTML

```
<div class="header">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://sii.italtamira.edu.mx/sistema/">SII</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.italtamira.edu.mx">Pagina web</a></li>
                <li class="derecha"><a href=""><?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['nombre']?></a></li>
                <li class="derecha"><a href="">Prueba</a></li>
                <li class="derecha"><a href="informacion.php">Información</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Este es el css

```
.header{
    padding: 0;
    background-color: green;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.header ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.header>ul>li{
    display: inline-block;
}
.header ul li a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
}
.header ul li a:hover{
    background-color: #22ad1f;
    transition: 1s;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
.derecha{
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

es porque tu body o tu header tienen un margen, agrega esto a tu CSS.

```
body, header { margin: 0}
```

recuerda que para detectar eso puedes usar el inspeccionador de elementos de chrome

Comment: corregido vale.